# How to get TypeName with correct nullable

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I try to call this.asType().asTypeName().isNullable
isNullable - does not work correct.

I found a solution, but it does not look well:

```
fun Element.getTypeNameWithRealNullable(): TypeName {
    val annotation = this.getAnnotationMirror(Nullable::class)
    return annotation?.let {
        this.asType().asTypeName().copy(nullable = true)
    } ?: this.asType().asTypeName().copy(nullable = false)
}

fun <T : Annotation> Element.getAnnotationMirror(type: KClass<T>): AnnotationMirror? {
    return this.getAnnotation(type.java.name)
}
```

Do kotlinpoet has better way for get correct isNullable?

Comment: Trying to understand what your code is doing: are you trying to infer the nullability of an `Element` based on the presence of the `Nullable` annotation? What does `Element` represent here? What does your code produce and where do you think it breaks?

Comment: Bear in mind that since kapt actually runs annotation processors over stubs, which are Java files, a lot of the Kotlin-specific information is lost, such as type nullability for instance. Because of that, we're currently in the process of deprecating Mirror API integrations in KotlinPoet and moving towards Kotlin Metadata API, the repo has more information on that.